# How to make a player walk over the network

Tags: unity, c#, networking, multiplayer, unity-networking

First of all, it is a newbie question and I am a noob so ya.

I am working on `Unity` with `low level network API`. I am able to connect multiple client's to the server and they spawn on clients.
All the clients get the information about the location of the other connected player, that is `transform.position` (ie. x, y and z coordinates) 
Position of all players is updated on all clients, that is, their `transform.position` gets updated with new available coordinates.

**The question:**
How do I simulate walking animation (of connected players) on client's screens? (I use `Unity's` `Horizontal` and `Vertical` input)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of multiplayer online game development, you will find that a lot of stuff is a mix of cheating and interpolation. For example you want to be able to know when to play a walk animation on remote client's screens? Then get the old position aof the object to animate and the new position just received and compute its velocity using the difference in the time stamp of those (yes, you should start using time stamps on your messages).

I cannot be more percise because the argument is very huge. I can suggest you some very useful and informative read that will guide you in this magical word. First of all [this](http://www.gabrielgambetta.com/client-server-game-architecture.html) important series of articles from Gabriel Gambetta, and then this very useful [website](https://gafferongames.com/post/physics_in_3d/) with articles about physics in 3d and how to network it.

Hope you are satisfied with my answer, good luck with your learning.